# Drupal. How to show list of referencing nodes in parent node view?

Tags: drupal-6

It's probably very basic but I didn't figure out how to do this. I tries NoreReferrer module but with no luck.

I created content type (let's name it Superdnode) that have only title and icon and is a container for content type Childnode.

On my homepage I have a block with listing Supernodes.

What I am trying to do is after clicking on node instead of show current node values I want to show list of all childnodes (referencing nodes).

Could somebody give me advice?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

NodeReferrer can help you - you can add NodeReferrer cck field and configure it to show what you want. Or you may try http://drupal.org/project/reverse_node_reference module, but it has no arguments support. Also you can make view that lists all nodes referencing and include that view in node display. There are many node reference modules that does what you need... for example this... http://drupalmodules.com/module/node-relationships